# Cannot Create Activex Component - When Calling Accredo COM dll

Tags: vb.net, com, activex, activexobject

I am working on an integration with a product called Accredo using COM. But I am getting the famous *Cannot create ActiveX component* when I try to create a COM object for Accredo from a webservice. I have looked at some of the other questions that relate to this on stack overflow but no luck. Things I have checked:

1. Accredo has been registered as a COM server during its installation by running C:\AccredoSaturn\AccredoSaturn.exe /regserver
2. The webservice is running under IIS 7.5 and is running as the localsystem user with the app pool set to enable 32bit applications.
3. This happens whenever the application is run, even if the pool is recycled and the site restarted. It is not intermittent.
4. I am debugging the webservice in VS2010 running as admin.
5. The webproject is targeted to the x86 framework.

Heres the line that throws the exception in vb.net:

```
App = CreateObject("AccredoSaturn.Application")
```

Is there anything else I can try or something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Is it working outside of IIS, for example in a VBScript command line with the same code?

Comment: Hi Simon, no it doesn't seem to be working outside of IIS. I am getting the same "Cannot create ActiveX Component" exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much time debugging the code, I found that this was being caused by the COM object not being disposed when an exception was thrown. Damn.